# How to make a vertical stem plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the next stem plot

```
plt.stem(m)
```

[image: stem plot 1]

and I want it but 90 degrees clockwise rotated. I've tried with

```
plt.stem(m,np.arange(m.size))
```

And obtain the next plot

[image: stem plot 2]

The expecting result it's something like the R(t) of the next image:
https://subsurfwiki.org/images/4/43/Convolutional_model.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With matplotlib>= 3.4.0 ([release notes here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html)), you can specify `orientation='horizontal'` in the `stem` function (see doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html)):

Example below from the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stem_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stem-plot-py):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1, 2 * np.pi, 41)
y = np.exp(np.sin(x))

plt.stem(x,y, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

and:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1, 2 * np.pi, 41)
y = np.exp(np.sin(x))

plt.stem(x,y, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image]